# I cannot get AvaloniaUi (Android, IOS, Browser) to build in mac M1 Rider

Tags: macos, apple-m1, rider, avaloniaui

so am trying to build Avalonia Cross Platform UI to build on Mac M1. Unfortunately, I have only been able to get the Avalonia.Desktop to run, I have followed all the available instructions I can find online but to no avail. I have also installed and restored all the needed workloads, but no luck. I tried running the app on Visual Studio for Mac 2022 and was able to successfully run the Android project.

Below are the errors, the build shows. Am targetting .net7 and using Avalonia template version 11.0.2

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5): Error NETSDK1147 : To build this 
project, the following workloads must be installed: android
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
1>------- Finished building project: AvaloniaApplication1.Android. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0

3>Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5): Error NETSDK1147 : To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: ios
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
3>------- Finished building project: AvaloniaApplication1.iOS. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
4>Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5): Error NETSDK1147 : To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: wasm-tools
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
4>------- Finished building project: AvaloniaApplication1.Browser. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
```

Any help is most welcome thank you.

Comment: You can help yourself by reading into MSBuild bin log, https://msbuildlog.com/ Once you are sure it is a bug that needs Microsoft attention, you can report to https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues

Comment: I have a very similar issue. trying to build a MAUI project in Linux using Rider, getting the exact error. I have installed/reinstalled all the needed workloads too.

Has anyone found a solution for this?